# Как родительскому элементу добавить в data-* атрибуты значения дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript, frontend

Есть условно 10 item вот такой структуры

```
<a href="#" class="movies-list__item">
   <div class="movies-list__poster">
     <img class="movies-list__img" src="../src/img/Russian_doll.jpg"></img>
     <span class="movies-list__company movies-list__company-netflix">Netflix</span>
   </div>
   <div class="movies-list__descr">
     <span class="movies-list__name">Russian Doll</span>
     <span class="movies-list__age">2019, </span>
     <span class="movies-list__type">Tv</span>
   </div>
   <div class="ratings movies-list__ratings">
      <div class="ratings__tomato">
         <div class="ratings__score">97%</div>
       </div>
       <div class="ratings__popcorn">
         <div class="ratings__score">87%</div>
       </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Нужно для каждого главного родительского элемента в item, т.е для `<a href="#" class="movies-list__item">` добавить data атрибуты со значениями некоторых дочерних элементов.
Т.е. для моего примера это будет выглядеть так `<a href="#" class="movies-list__item" data-type="Tv" data-age="2019" data-company="Netflix">`

У меня есть идея как это сделать. Собрать массивы всех movies-list__age , movies-list__type, movies-list__company и добавить их значения в item. Например так:

```
const moviesList = document.querySelector('.movies-list');
const arrMoviesItems = [...moviesList.children];
const moviesType =  document.querySelectorAll('.movies-list__item .movies-list__type');
const arrMoviesType = [...moviesType];

    for(i = 0; i<=arrMoviesType.length;i++){
       arrMoviesItems[i].setAttribute('data-type', arrMoviesType[i].innerText.toLowerCase())
}
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что есть более нормальное решение как можно вытянуть значения дочерних тегов в data атрибут родителя `<a href="#" class="movies-list__item">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это что-то верно подсказывает.

```js
const arrMoviesItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.movies-list').children];

for(let i = 0; i <= arrMoviesType.length; i++) { // У вас тут ошибка, забыли let
  let current = arrMoviesItems[i];

  current.dataset.type = // Специальное api для работы с data-*
    current.querySelector('.movies-list__type').textContent; // current.querySelector вернёт элемент таким селектором ВНУТРИ current
  current.dataset.age =
    current.querySelector('.movies-list__age').textContent; // В примере было data-company="Netflix", зачем же тогда .toLowerCase()?
  current.dataset.company =
    current.querySelector('.movies-list__company').textContent;
}
```

Comment: Если честно свой код на коленке написал, даже не смотрел работает ли он. Хотел донести какие есть мысли как это сделать. То есть это нормальный вариант такого заполнения data атрибутов? Просто думал что мой вариант это  больше костыль чем решение)))) И за это "current.querySelector вернёт элемент таким селектором ВНУТРИ current" отдельное спасибо, не знал.

Comment: Да, если что на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) про `dataset` неплохо написано.